# Move semantics & argument evaluation order

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, operator-precedence

Considering the following:

```
std::string make_what_string( const std::string &id );

struct basic_foo
{
    basic_foo( std::string message, std::string id );
};

struct foo
    : public basic_foo
{
    foo::foo( std::string id)
        : basic_foo( make_what_string( id ), std::move( id ) ) // Is this valid?
    {
    }
};
```

Because parameter evaluation order in C++ is unspecified, I'm wondering if
the line

```
basic_foo( make_what_string( id ), std::move( id ) )
```

in above code is valid.

I know that `std::move` is nothing more than a cast, but when is the std::string
move ctor executed? After all arguments have been evaluated and it's time to call
the base constructor? Or is this done during evaluation of the parameters? In
other words:

Does the compiler do this:

```
std::string &&tmp2 = std::move(id);
std::string tmp1 = make_what_string(id);
basic_foo(tmp1, tmp2);
```

which is valid. Or this:

```
std::string tmp2 = std::move(id);
std::string tmp1 = make_what_string(id);
basic_foo(tmp1, tmp2);
```

which is invalid. Note that in both cases the order is the "unexpected"
one.

Comment: Actually, the code is valid. However, I believe you meant to take the string `id` in `base_foo`'s constructor by rvalue reference rather than by value (didn't you?).

Comment: @CassioNeri, No the code is as intended :)

Comment: Yes, I realized that during lunch time. :-) Very nice question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See section 1.9:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

and

> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function. [ *Note*: Value computations and side effects associated with different argument expressions are unsequenced. —*end note* ]

I think the problem is that it's not very clear whether the initialization of the parameters is considered a side effect associated with the argument expressions. However, it appears to be backed up by section 5.2.2:

> The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the
>   calling function.

And there's also a note in the same paragraph that makes it a little clearer:

> When a function is called, each parameter (8.3.5) shall be initialized (8.5, 12.8, 12.1) with its corresponding argument. [ *Note*: Such initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other (1.9) — *end note* ]

So yes, the initialization of the arguments are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other. The initializations might occur in either of these orders:

```
std::string message = make_what_string(id);
std::string id = std::move( id );

std::string id = std::move( id );
std::string message = make_what_string(id);
```

In the second case, `make_what_string` ends up working with a moved-from string.

So, even though `std::move` doesn't actually move anything, the important thing is that the actual *moving* is also unsequenced with respect to the other argument.

The definition of the move constructor of `basic_string(basic_string&& str)` states:

> [...] `str` is left in a valid state with an unspecified value.

So you don't have undefined behaviour, you have unspecified behaviour.

Comment: @David: yes, because the moved from string might no longer be valid, depending on the implementation

Comment: @Tom Actually, it's unspecified, not undefined. :)

Comment: i think the normative argument can be: either the parameters are initialized before or after the function call. after the function call is impossible. hence it must happen before. And parameter initialization is normatively defined to happen in the context of the caller (so it is not evaluated "in the body of the called function"). So there is no sequencing (and no transitive sequencing) of the parameter initialization with respect to the argument evaluations.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Good point. I just found that quote too. I'll add it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yes, but another possibility could also be, 1) evaluate all args first 2) initialize all parameters next 3) execute call. This way everything happens in the context of the caller and the code would still be correct.

Comment: @Tom Sure, that's one possibility. But there are other possibilities, which makes it unspecified behaviour. Your program has multiple possible execution paths it could take. One that leads to defined behaviour, and the other that leads to more unspecified behaviour. It's irrelevant though; you have unspecified behaviour.

Comment: Also see https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-discussion/J_EzBul5iYM/36hPL1O6fYIJ

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Interesting. Does that make the note "Such initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other (1.9)" incorrect?

Comment: @sftrabbit yes that note is wrong, because "indeterminately sequenced" means that the initializations could not overlap each other. That is not even true for the class types case in some cases, because in those cases sometimes there may be two function calls being done for a single initialization (one on a conversion function of the initializer expression's class object, and one on a copy/move constructor of the parameter type's class object, if not elided. In between, another initialization may interfere).

Comment: Also consider this: `int x = 0; void f(int a, int b) { cout << a << b; } struct A { operator int&() { x++; return x; } }; int main() { f(A(), A()); }`. it could happen that `f` outputs `1 2` or `2 1` (would would be required if the the initializations would be "indeterminately sequenced"). But it could also happen that it outputs `2 2` (the initializations are interleaved, a possible consequence of them being unsequenced). ICC outputs "2 2" for me, GCC "2 1" and Clang "1 2" (all at -O2).

Answer (score 7):

It's not really valid. The order of function argument evaluation is unspecified. In other words, you don't know whether the compiler will choose this sequence:

```
tmp1 = make_what_string(id);
tmp2 = std::move(id);
basic_foo(tmp1, tmp2);
```

or this one:

```
tmp1 = std::move(id);
tmp2 = make_what_string(id);  //id has already been moved from!
basic_foo(tmp2, tmp1);
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've updated my question to better specify what I'm asking.

Comment: But `std::move` itself doesn't actually move anything, it only casts to an rvalue reference.

Comment: @interjay: Indeed; but (as the question describes) forming the function argument's value from the result of `std::move` *does* move it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I know, but the "invalid" code shown in this answer is actually valid, assuming that `tmp1` is an rvalue reference. As sftrabbit's answer says, the issue is with the order of parameter initialization, not the order of argument evaluation.

Comment: the question is whether the argument evaluation includes the initialization of the parameters or not.